# Column Relationship between DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL and DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have been trying to find out which column in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL links to DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY but haven't succeeded up to this point.

My goal is to get the sql statements for each session in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL using sql_id in DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY,

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL does not store SQL_ID but stores sql statement source code with bind variables and DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESSION works mainly with SQL_ID without sql statement source code.

Comment: I'm only interested to know if there is any relationship between the tables then navigate from there once i have linked the two